# How to delete SqLite file in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm having a problem with deleting the SQLite file from my application. 
I'm using the code as follows:

```
File file = new File("data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/*****");             
d = file.delete();
DbAdapter dba = new DbAdapter(context);
dba.open();
dba.close();
```

Before this, I was using the method `context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME)` to do this.
The problem is: after I run this method, the application does not refresh, I have the old database and I am able to do deletes, inserts, etc.
On both cases I have to restart my application to see the new database.

Sometimes, after to run the method, when I try to access some methods that need the database, the app crashes with an error that I have no database and after restart, the new database is created.

What do I do?

**EDIT**
I have a big system. My database have 26 tables and a lot of constraingns.
It's easier to delete the database and recreate it.

**EDIT2**

```
DbAdapter dba = new DbAdapter(context);
SQLiteDatabase sqlite = dba.open();         

dba.close();
boolean d = context.deleteDatabase("CarroramaBD");

dba.open();
dba.close();
```

Im did close the db.

Comment: Any specific reasons to delete database and not just empty tables or fields? It is more appropriate then deleting and then creating entire database everytime. Anyhow see this answer for your problems http://stackoverflow.com/a/3598769/1979347

Comment: I have a big system. My database have 26 tables and a lot of constraingns.

Comment: Did you close all database connections before calling deleteDatabase() ? I think in this case you wouldn't have to restart the app...

Comment: Yes, i dis close the databases.

Comment: An open file descriptor to a deleted file remains valid and the file remains until it is closed.  Perhaps you didn't close the database, or didn't do so in a way that closes the file handle inside the implementation.  You should probably do the delete through the APIs rather than behind their back.

Comment: I changed my code. Its getting the same bug yet.

Answer (score 0):

Why doing this
instead you can drop the tables in your db and recreate them which is far more practical than deleting the file.

And as for your views that store old values you can refresh the whole activity by calling this code

```
public void refrehs_me()
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Edit : Just a thought passed my mind regarding the creation of the new DB, On the creation of your app a DB file will be created, you make a copy of that file like DB2, and when you delete the DB instead of trying to create a new one just copy back DB2 as DB and so on with each deletion process.

And for the copy - here is the code by @Rakshi

```
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```